# Is there a way to get the RowCount of a specific column in Processing?

Tags: csv, processing

I am trying to get the RowCount of a specific column in my .csv file.

```
Table table;

float temperature = 15;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, 800);

table = loadTable("data/wetterAppSentences.csv", "header");

if (temperature <= 7){
  TableRow row = table.getRow(random(table.getRowCount()));
  
}
}
```

I tried using the header of my column to define it but .getRowCount() doesn't expect any arguments.

Comment: With `Table` you can only get the total number of columns, but you can't get a specific column. You can only get a list of rows. [`getRowCount()`](https://processing.org/reference/Table_getRowCount_.html) "Returns the **total** number of rows in a Table.". You might need to flip your problem around so you think of it in terms rows first instead of columns. (Once you get a `TableRow` you can check how columns it has via `yourRow.getColumnCount()` for example)